# How to join to a one to many relationship table?

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many

I have three tables, lets say for example table 1 is `locations`, then table 2 is `location_items` then table 3 is `items`

`location_items` is the link between `locations` and `items`

each `locations` has one `location_items` and each `location_items` has either one or more `items`

Column names:

locations table: location_id primary key

location_items table: location_items_id primary key, location_id foreign key, item_id foreign key(one is to many, 1 location, many items).

items table: item_id primary_key, name(name of the item that i want to get)

Now what I want is select the `locations`, then join to `location_items`, then join to `items` to get the lets say the first `items.name` that is not null. Here is my sample query:

```
SELECT l.location_id,COALESCE(i.name) 
            FROM locations l
            LEFT JOIN location_items li USING(location_id)
            LEFT JOIN items i USING(item_id)
            WHERE l.location_id LIKE '%P021%'
        GROUP BY l.location_id
```

But I only get all the location_ids with null name

Comment: Please give the table structure of all 3 table

Comment: Please give the columns names from each tables - Thanks

Comment: I think your result set has a null set for that particular location...can you verify you have names associated to location_ID like '%PO21%'? Your left joins may also be throwing you off. I suggest you create a sub-query to join on that aggregates the columns you're looking for from items, with their associated location_items ID, then you have one JOIN...might make more sense to you also.

Comment: Why do you have the location_items table at all? Typically, you use a table like location_items in a has and belongs to many (HABTM) relationship, not a has many relationship, like that between locations and items.